# Invert PyTorch Indexing

Tags: python, pytorch, slice, tensor

Suppose, I have a PyTorch tensor `a` of shape `ba,c,h,w` and wish to zero out some rows of `a` with indices given in another tensor `b` of shape `ba,2` of `dtype=torch.int16` and `b[batch, 0] <= b[batch, 1]`.

The for loop way of doing is:

```
for batch in range(ba):
    a[batch,:,0:b[batch,0],:] = 0  # stmnt 1
    a[batch,:,b[batch,1]:,:] = 0   # stmnt 2
```

Is there a faster PyTorch way to do this?

Specifically, firstly by combining stmnt1 and stmnt2 into a single line to tell PyTorch make all rows of `a` except `a[batch,:,b[batch,0]:b[batch,1],:]` zero. And secondly, if this can be done without needing to iterate over each batch using a `for` loop.

Comment: Both the batch size and the index tensor were termed with `b`, perhaps you want to rename one of them. Is it always true that `b[batch, 0] <= b[batch, 1]` for all `batch in range(b)`? Do you need to preserve gradients when performing this operation?

Comment: @aretor. Thanks for pointing out the error. I have edited the question with batch size renamed to `ba` and yes the condition you mentioned is always satisfied.